# Apple magic keyboard weird behavior

Tags: ios, keyboard, bluetooth, internationalization

I connected Apple's magic keyboard to an iPhone 7 and started to experiment if I can take it with me on a journey.

I soon realized that it does not have any special characters to my language. I started to search for a button that alters the letters to get those special chars (alt + letters; cmd + letters). After a while I discovered some strange behaviors of this keyboard:

- I can not type capital <kbd>T</kbd> with left <kbd>Shift</kbd>.
- <kbd>Backspace</kbd> works as delete button (removes text from right side of cursor).
- Right and left arrows works as HOME and END buttons.

Also I noticed that arrow keys and <kbd>backspace</kbd> works if I reconnect with device. Whenever I hit left <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> the phone opens dropdown menu to select onscreen keybord type (Emoji and two other options). After this again arrows and <kbd>backspace</kbd> does not work.

My guess is that I accidentally activated some mode to get a Latvian layout and now need to reverse that. Any way to fix this?

Keyboard model: A1314

Also I found a whole thread where people have exactly the same problem, but no solutions for years: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3357507

Comment: Latvian. It is regular latin with few additions. The keyboard alignment is the same QWERTY. Also I tried to change the keyboard layout to Englis US but the problem remains. Is there any way I can do a hard reset on keyboard?

Comment: Go to settings > general > keyboard > hardware keyboard.  Where it says Latvian on the left, tap at the right edge and make sure it says "Latvian" there too (and not "automatic". ) Then your hardware keyboard should act just like standard Mac Latvian layout, with the special characters on the Option key level.  For example you should get Option e = ē

Comment: @TomGewecke reopened for a proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to defer to people like @nohillside and @Tom Gewecke for internationalization and keyboard setups, but you can rule out a factory reset of Apple bluetooth devices quite quickly assuming you have a Mac computer you can borrow and pair to the keyboard in question.

1. Enable Bluetooth in the menu bar
2. Hold Shift and Option keys when you click on Bluetooth icon (and you can let go of the modifier keys once the menu is visible).
3. Choose **Debug - Factory reset all connected Apple devices** or choose the specific device - navigate to the sub menu and choose **Factory Reset**

I'm guessing this is less than 50% your issue, but if it does - you'll be set (or have fewer items to chase down) and know how to reset Apple Bluetooth devices.

Comment: Nop, did not work. The keyboard works normally until I want to type "T" (left shift + t). Then it enters that mode where arrows and backspace does not work.